# Replace whole <head> and <body> with ajax content

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox add-on which heuristically determines which web links the user is about to click on, and preemptively fetches the target documents for rapid access.

If the target document is an html page, its `head` and `body` are loaded and stored in advance into a json object and, when the user actually clicks the link, the json object replaces the `head` and `body` of the current page, so that no network activity is required to follow the link. History states are also handled by the add-on.

My add-on is in pre-alpha stage, but the concept works *most of the time*, specifically it works with any preemptively cached webpage which does not differ from the present page by having additional CSS and javascript. That is, any `script` tag and any reference to CSS files — such as `<link href=style.css type=text/css>` — retrieved from the new page is not executed / rendered when it is then injected into the current page.

The add-on fires the `load` event to `window` after DOM injection completes, but to no avail.

Is there a way I could force the browser to reparse the whole DOM and execute / parse its `<script>`s and CSS as if it were a freshly-downloaded webpage?

Comment: this is the deal breaker that made me abandon a related project a few years back. you can make it work with your own specially-handled JS, but not just any JS, and especially not $.ready() -using jQuery plugins, which is a "big deal". plus, you need to un-bind old handlers, or common slideshows will skip two images per click and other whacky RAM-wasting side-effects like that.

Comment: its better to explain here what problems you get when you're replacing the content with ajax.

Comment: Quoting from my post:
"That is, any script tag and any reference to CSS files retrieved from the new page is not executed / rendered when it is then injected into the current page."

Comment: That's weird because when you do inject script.css into the page it should take affect. How are you injecting it? Are you doing createElement and then appending? If you are and its still a problem, try doing createElementNS with the HTML namesapce.